# SMS Manager is sending more than one sms

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String msg = "some text";
    sendSMS("xxxxxxxxx", msg);
}
```

I've got code like above. The problem is that when I run the application it sends one message after another. How to make it send one and only one sms?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the this is in your `MainActivity` class.
When you send the PendingIntent you send it to the same activity. The activity is then recreated and `onCreate` is called again.

If you really want to send the SMS in `onCreate` then send the Intent to another Activity. Otherwise create a button and send the SMS in the `onClick` event of the button.